# Call all php scripts via ajax?

Tags: php, ajax, performance, security

The idea is that I call all of my php scripts via ajax so the php scripts aren't visible when a user views the sourcecode.

Is this a good ideal especially regarding security and performance of my website?

Comment: The way you make a request to your server is completely unrelated from security / performance topics.

Comment: PHP scripts aren't visible to a user anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The PHP code that you write will never been seen by the end user - the code is executed by the server and returns everything outside of the PHP tags (`<?php ... ?>`). The PHP code inside the tags is NOT returned to the browser.

As far as using AJAX is concerned this won't help you with security, your AJAX calls are only as secure or unsecure as standard GET or POST requests to the server. What AJAX may help you with is performance since it allows you to send and recieve data in the background. If your application is data-centric then AJAX will be useful to communicate pure data with the server. If you have a standard hierarchical website design then there's little user for AJAX, just use links to move around and forms to send data.